# Where are "notifications" in the new topbar-design?

Tags: support, design, top-bar, notification-bar

I cannot find the good old "notifications"-section in the new...lets say layout. Is it just scapped, does it have a new location or am I just missing something obvious?

To be clear : It is the `StackExchange▼` drop down box I am referring to.

Comment: Notification of what particular type?

Comment: @random, that was quick :) notifications like "you earned a new badge". Know for a fact that i've got a new one, and usually we get informed in the dropdown, under the section "notifications" - now there is only links to comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badges and rep are included in the "achievements" section.

Chat messages, edits, answers and comments are included in "inbox" section.

Comment: Silly me :( Thank you!